# How does Kafka stream get distributed among TaskManagers in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Say a Flink Job (three task managers `tm1`,`tm2` & `tm3`) consumes Kafka topic as a source, how does the stream gets distributed among them? Who does the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

This is done in `FlinkKafkaConsumerBase`, in its `open()` method. The Flink runtime context provides methods that each instance can use to determine the total number of parallel instances of the Flink Kafka consumer, as well as the index of a specific instance. Each instance uses these methods to independently take responsibility for reading from specific partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what David wrote you should keep one thing in mind: The max. parallism of a KafkaProducer is limited by the number of partitions. Since Flink will start distributing the tasks starting with the first slot (the first task-manager) and then go on with the 2nd and so on and repeat this for each source, you might see an unbalanced workload if you have more task-managers than topic-partitions.

In a scenario where you have many kafka-sources with a small number of topic-partitions this imbalance becomes more and more visible. In an extrem case you have many sources with only one partition all this sources will get consumed by the first slot/task-manager. You can work around this edge case if you use [Slot sharing groups](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/#task-chaining-and-resource-groups). This is of course an edge case but it might be good to have this in your mind when you define your resources and workflows.